# Ar toolkit nftBook with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, artoolkit

### How to solve artoolkit nftBook issues in android studio

When I run the command ndk-build in android studio terminal for nft book it shows the error like:

> clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation) make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libnftBookNative.so]
>   Error 1

How can I solve this?

Comment: Include more of the error message. All that line says is "there was an error".

Answer (score 1):

You should not run it in the android studio terminal but in the Git-Bash. 
Read the documentation more closely :).

You look like you are working from Windows so you need to use Git-Bash for compilation.

See: http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=17092

===========

EDIT:

Make sure you have these environment variables set:
- Set ANDROID_HOME to indicate the path to root folder of the downloaded Android SDK.

- Set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to indicate the path to root folder (most likely, “ndk-bundle”) of the downloaded NDK. The ANDROID_HOME environment variable can be used to help define NDK.
- ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
- Set NDK to the same path as ANDROID_NDK_ROOT. NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
- Set PATH to include a path to the ndk-build[.cmd] script file, that is, the path to the root folder of the NDK. The NDK environment variable can be used to help define the added path.

---

- Now start gitBash and navigate to your ARToolKit5_ROOT directory.
- cd android
- ./build.sh
  if successful
- ./build_native_examples.sh

Comment: i have installed gitbash..can you show me the steps how to run in gitbash?

Comment: When I run build.sh command I got the error like "development platform not supported,exiting script"

Comment: Help me how can do this?

Comment: ok, now I need a detailed description of your setup and your system. Otherwise I cannot help. Cause I don't understand what you are doing.